# Enable a button after one minute in angular

Tags: angular, angularjs

On my page I’ve a button and I want that it’s disabled by default, but, after 1 Minute this button become enabled. Pls anyone help me.

Comment: you can `setTimeout` to do that, but is not good practice

Answer (score 1):

in your html you should do something like this
HTML:

```
<button [disabled]="disabled">Click me!</button>
```

and your ts file should be something like this

TS:

```
  disabled: boolean = true;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.disabled = false;
    }, 60000);
  }
```